# Python Multiprocess/Threading loop.

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

What i am trying to do is to check which multiprocessing is best for my data. I  tried to multiprocess this loop:

```
def __pure_calc(args):

    j = args[0]
    point_array = args[1]
    empty = args[2]
    tree = args[3] 

    for i in j:
            p = tree.query(i)   

            euc_dist = math.sqrt(np.sum((point_array[p[1]]-i)**2))  

            ##add one row at a time to empty list
            empty.append([i[0], i[1], i[2], euc_dist, point_array[p[1]][0], point_array[p[1]][1], point_array[p[1]][2]]) 

    return empty
```

Just pure function is taking **6.52 sec.**

My first approach was multiprocessing.map:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 

def __multiprocess(las_point_array, point_array, empty, tree):

    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count()) 

    for j in las_point_array:
        args=[j, point_array, empty, tree]
        results = pool.map(__pure_calc, args)

    #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
    pool.close() 
    pool.join() 

    return results
```

When i checked other answers how to multiprocess function it should be easy as that: map(call function, inputs) - done.  But for some reason my multiproccess is not excepting my inputs, rising error that scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree object is not subscriptable.

So i tried with apply_async:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def __multiprocess(arSegment, wires_point_array, ptList, tree):

    pool = ThreadPool(os.cpu_count())

    args=[arSegment, point_array, empty, tree]

    result = pool.apply_async(__pure_calc, [args])

    results = result.get()
```

It run with out problems. For my test data i manage to calculate it in **6.42 sec.**

Why apply_async is accepting ckdtree with out any problem and pool.map not? What i need to change to make it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pool.map(function, iterable)`, it basically has the same footprint with itertool's `map`. Each item from the iterable will be the `args` for your `__pure_calc` function.

In this case I guess you might change into this:

```
def __multiprocess(las_point_array, point_array, empty, tree):

    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count()) 

    args_list = [
        [j, point_array, empty, tree]
        for j in las_point_array
    ]

    results = pool.map(__pure_calc, args_list)

    #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
    pool.close() 
    pool.join() 

    return results
```